# Sorting using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code below

```
Dim Lasteuro As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("A2:AF").Sort Key1:=Range("T2:T"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("V:V"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Lasteuro = Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array("LNCCP", "LNLCHSCM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues


'Sec No.'
Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("D2:D" & Lasteuro).Copy
Sheets("Master").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'Cpty Name'
Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("F2:F" & Lasteuro).Copy
Sheets("Master").Range("L6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'Break'
Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("I2:I" & Lasteuro).Copy
Sheets("Master").Range("M6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'Age'
Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("P2:P" & Lasteuro).Copy
Sheets("Master").Range("P6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Euro Cash").ShowAllData
```

However upon running, I get:

> Run-time error '1004' : Method Range of object _Global failed.

I clicked on debug, it highlights this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("A2:AF").Sort Key1:=Range("T2:T"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("V:V"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

So what I did is change `Thisworkbook.Sheets` to `Sheets` - still same error..
what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) within the [Range .Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) is open to interpretation as to what the parent worksheet is.

```
Dim Lasteuro As Long

With Sheets("Euro Cash")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    Lasteuro = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A:AF").Sort Key1:=.Columns(20), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(22), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Header:=xlYes

    .Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array("LNCCP", "LNLCHSCM"), _
                             Operator:=xlFilterValues
    'Sec No.'
    .Range("D2:D" & Lasteuro).Copy
    Sheets("Master").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Cpty Name'
    .Range("F2:F" & Lasteuro).Copy
    Sheets("Master").Range("L6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Break'
    .Range("I2:I" & Lasteuro).Copy
    Sheets("Master").Range("M6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Age'
    .Range("P2:P" & Lasteuro).Copy
    Sheets("Master").Range("P6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Note the use of `.Range` and not `Range`. This means that the parent is the one defined in the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). You are only required to indicate the first cell when defining the key.

After looking closer at all of your code (and reviewing the comments provided) I've changed the sort range so that it recognizes the column header labels in row 1.

Comment: do i use T2 and V3? not "T:T" and "V:V"?

Comment: You can declare each key as the top cell or the whole column. It is just personally preference. btw, it should be T2 and V2, not T2 and V3.

Comment: im now getting application-defined or object defined error

Comment: Dim Lasteuro As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Euro Cash")
        .Range("A2:AF").Sort Key1:=.Range(T), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range(V), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
    
    Lasteuro = Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets("Euro Cash").Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array("LNCCP", "LNLCHSCM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: It concerns me that you are using a range that starts in row 2 and stating that you have a header but later using full column references for the autofilter. Ar your column header labels in row 1 or row 2?

Comment: my header label is at row 1. i changed the T and V to T2 and V2. still encountering same error

Comment: After looking closer at all of your code (and reviewing the comments provided) I've changed the sort range so that it recognizes the column header labels in row 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83601/discussion-between-pucktack-and-jeeped).

Comment: i did the code u provided. upon running it promtps me to this: the sort reference is not valid. make sure that it is within the data you want to sort, and the first sort by box isnt the same or blank